# When unit testing a directive how to pass its controller

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive, controller

I am new to AngularJS and its unit test. Currently I am trying to test a directive with its controller in the template file:

It's template:

```
<div ng-controller = "SomeController" >
<select ng-model="data.selectedOption" 
        ng-options="data.code for data in data.availableOptions track by data.code">
</select>
</div>
```

It's js file:

```
angular.module('application.directives')
  .directive('selector', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'templates.html'
     };
  });
```

Now I have a unit test like:

```
describe('selector', function () {
  beforeEach(module('application.directives','application.templates'));

  it('render the correct number of items', inject(function ($rootScope, $compile) {
    var element = $compile('<selector></selector>')($rootScope);
    $rootScope.$digest();
    //I'd like to register the selector's controller here.
  }));
});
```

In the test code, what would be the best way to register the controller? Do I need to create a mock one?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the controller `SomeController` is in the same module `application.directives`, you need not have to too anything. The controller will be available while testing the directive.

[Here is the sample code in jsfiddle for similar case](http://jsfiddle.net/wFFet/181/)

If the controller is in different module.

[Here is the sample code in jsfiddle for this case](http://jsfiddle.net/ujofvmum/1/)